# Javascript injected into iframe of same origin not working

Tags: javascript

In the parent window, I have this script

```
 function injectJS() {
 var myIframe = document.getElementById("MyFrame");
 var script = myIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 script.src = "/myscript.js";
 myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
 }
```

then for my iframe, I have

```
 <iframe id="MyFrame" onload="injectJS()"></iframe>
```

As I inspect the iframe element, I see the script tag has been inserted with it's source being the script I wanted /myscript.js. So everything appears to be working however the script is not working. Nothing is wrong with the script as it works fine everywhere else. What could be causing it to not work in the iframe even though the script tag was successfully injected and links to the script I want loaded.

Comment: How do you know the script in /myscript.js doesn't run?  What's in it that you're expecting?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Network tab?

Comment: If simply run alert in `myscript.js`, the file is performing, may be problem in your scripts at `myscript.js`

Comment: I'm expecting a simple alert message just for testing purposes. It works everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, myscript does run an alert. Not working though.

Comment: Is it possible to show the `scripts` at `myscript.js` which are not working?

Comment: can you use the console in the context of the iframe to see if any variables are being created from `myscript`?